# Can I manage database using database project without knowing connection string?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac

I have created database project. I am able to upgrade my changes in my sql server. Now I have deploy the same changes on another environment. Also I don`t want to change my previous data. I don`t have to access that Sql server so I don`t know the connection string.

I have some options, like to deploy the .dacpac file or .sql script, but it first delete the database then creates new one. So that I loosing my data.

Please help me. If any option is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options I see for this are:

- Ask for a backup (or extract schema tables using task-->Generate scripts ion ssms) - restore this somewhere and use sqlpackage to generate a deployment script you can ask them to run
- Ask them to run sqlpackage.exe and either generate a script or run it directly
- Ask them for permissions so you can do it

**If the database is being deleted then you have the option "CreateNewDatabase" set to true which would be bad in a production environment so remove it or set it to false!**

If they run it or you ask for permissions, these are the minimum permissions you need to generate a script (to run the script you will probably need dbo):

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/What-Permissions-Do-I-Need-To-Generate-A-Deploy-Script-With-SSDT (my blog)

Comment: where is option "CreateNewDatabase"?

Comment: Are you using sqlpackage, the publish in visual studio or the merge tool?

Comment: No. I am using Upgrade Data-tier Application in Sql Server 2012.
But I think that Sqlpackage,exe is much better to publish. Right?

Comment: yes, don't use the ssms wizard it is pretty poor - I really need to write it up but all you do is use sqlpackage.exe with  /Action:Script and it will generate a deployment script (you also need to pass in the name of the server and db and have the permissions I mentioned above)

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. 
Please give if any other suggestion.

Comment: Ravindra, the CreateNewDatabase option is probably your main culprit, but look into Publish Profiles as well to be able to hand off the changes to someone else and have them run it through the Publish Profile. I've written a series on SSDT that could be helpful here (don't know if Ed has similar, but check his out if he does) - http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html